# Accessing more than one identical TWAIN or WIA device at the same time

Tags: windows-7, drivers, twain

I have an application that I am building that requires me to use four Epson V33/V37 scanners. The application is being  detrimente by the fact that all four will access the same drivers to work and so only the first scanner will have the ability to connect via TWAIN and the rest will be denied access. The application works perfectly well with difference model scanners attached.  Is there a way I can copy the drivers to new folder and then change the path where each scanner accesses a "different" driver?